# FileNotFoundException on HttpsURLConnection with POST and unmutable doOutput variable

Tags: java, android, httpsurlconnection

I'm trying to POST some data to an https url, in my android application, in order to get a json format response.

I'm facing two problems:

> is = conn.getInputStream();

throws

> java.io.FileNotFoundException

I don't get if i do something wrong with HttpsURLConnection.

The second problem arose when i debug the code (used eclipse); I set a breakpoint after

> conn.setDoOutput(true);

and, when inspecting `conn` values, I see that the variable `doOutput` remain set to `false` and type `GET`.

---

My method for https POST is the following, where `POSTData` is a class extending `ArrayList<NameValuePair>`

```
private static String httpsPOST(String urlString, POSTData postData,  List<HttpCookie> cookies) {

    String result = null;
    HttpsURLConnection conn = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    InputStream is = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setUseCaches (false);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        if(cookies != null)
            conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie",
                    TextUtils.join(";", cookies));

        os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(postData.getPostData());
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        is = conn.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder(); 
        String line;
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line);
        }
        result = total.toString();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (os != null) {
            try {
                os.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
        if (is != null) {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

---

A little update: apparently eclipse debug lied to me, running and debugging on netbeans shows a `POST` connection. Error seems to be related to parameters i'm passing to the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileNotFoundException` means that the URL you posted to doesn't exist, or couldn't be mapped to a servlet. It is the result of an HTTP 404 status code.

Don't worry about what you see in the debugger if it doesn't agree with how the program behaves. If `doOutput` really wasn't enabled, you would get an exception obtaining the output stream.